# Laravel 10 Backpack 6.x - custom data in custom show or list view

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-10

I am currently working on a project in Laravel 10 using Backpack v6.x

I am stuck with trying to access custom data in my show,list,create crud pages. A sample is this with my list  operation

```
protected function setupListOperation()
{
    $this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->where('status', 'processing');

    $this->crud->addColumn('user_id');
    $this->crud->addColumn('total_price');
    $this->crud->addColumn('payment_status');
    $this->crud->addColumn('status');

    $this->data=["test"];
    $this->crud->setListView('custom.crud.order.list');
  
}
```

How can I access the data in my view blade?

I tried $data, $crud->data but I am getting nowhere.

If this is wrong, what is the best way to pass data to my custom view pages?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find how to access the custom data.

In the crud controller, add the object inside the data array

```
$this->data["test"]="test data";
```

Then to be able to access it in the view, call the key name

```
var_dump($test);
// test data
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future since I couldnt find it in any of the documentation.